# how to match regex field with given string in elasticsearch (text to regex match)

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

my json example

```
obj=[{'id':1,'name':'dhaka','pattern':'dha*ka*'},
{'id':2,'name':'cumilla','pattern':'(c|k)(u|o)+m(i|e)l+a+'},...]
```

query string: `homna kumilla`
I want to fetch the docs whose pattern allow the string

```
Expected result
{'id':2,'name':'cumilla','pattern':'(c|k)(u|o)+m(i|e)l+a+'}
```

How will be the mappings and query?

Comment: Can you share your mapping and setting?

Comment: simple mappings, name as text, and pattern as wildcard, so how will be the query?

Comment: What is the purpose of pattern field

Comment: I want to fetch the docs whose pattern allow the string

Comment: thats the reason you want to get the `Kumila` when you index doc has `Cumila` cause in your pattern you consider `C` and `K` same?

Comment: yes, thats why i use pattern

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244209/discussion-between-amit-and-rafiqul-islam).